# entity framework 6 fails under load testing with 10 request per seconds

Tags: load-testing, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

**Project Settings:** EF6 + WebAPi + Self hosted executable running on development computer

**Usage of EF6:** Repository Patttern

**Testing Tool:** LoadUI from another XP machine(Virtual machine)

**Problem:** As soon as i enter 10 request perseconds i get following error. With 5 or 6 ,7 requests per seconds everything just works fine.

It's weird that if i test it via visual studio 2013 Test Project everything seems to work fine for 1000 requests => *0,003 s- 0, 004s seconds per request.*

How should i handle this problem? 
    How can i prevent self hosted web server shutting down, crushing or waiting?

[image]

Comment: Can anyone suggest an idea please?

Comment: You can't address one context from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. How should i prevent it from happening? Should i use lock() on context? or any other idea?

Comment: And I am using my context with "using clause" 
like this.
using (var cotext = .... ) {//do some work}

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: something like this =>
using (var ctx = new TestDBContext())
    {
        ctx.Items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
     }

Comment: To add to Gert's response - if you are sharing your context across multiple requests (i.e. as a static variable) this would result in multiple threads using the same instance which which won't work because - as pointed by Gert - the context is not thread safe.

Comment: how am i sharing context across multiple requests? i thought "using" keyword takes care of that. I dont know how to share context between requests and how not to.

Comment: should i use IsSubmitting property somehow? or some way queue requests?